# How to correctly map Model to Entity in Automapper 6.1.1?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using automapper in my project and until today was with the very old version of it and I decided to update it to the latest version.

When executing my project and testing some apis, some worked normally (without relationships), but others appeared the following error:

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types:
> PaginaModelCadastro -> Pagina
> Identidade.App.Models.PaginaModelCadastro -> Identidade.Domain.Entities.Pagina
>
> Type Map configuration:
> PaginaModelCadastro -> Pagina
> Identidade.App.Models.PaginaModelCadastro -> Identidade.Domain.Entities.Pagina
> Property:
> IdDominio

Following is all classes and mappings that refer to the error:

** Automapper configuration class **

```
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(map =>
        {
            map.AddProfile<EntityToModelMapping>();
            map.AddProfile<ModelToEntityMapping>();
        });
    }
```

**Mapping from model to entity**

```
        CreateMap<PaginaModelCadastro, Pagina>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IdDominio, src => src.MapFrom(m => new Dominio() { IdDominio = m.IdDominio }));
```

**Class: Dominio**

```
public class Dominio
{
    public virtual int IdDominio { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pagina> Paginas { get; set; }
}
```

**Class: Pagina**

```
public class Pagina
{
    public virtual int IdPagina { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual int IdDominio { get; set; }

    public virtual Dominio Dominio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permissao> Permissoes { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to map between IdDominio and Dominio. You have to remove that ForMember you have. Maybe you meant

```
    CreateMap<PaginaModelCadastro, Pagina>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Dominio, src => src.MapFrom(m => new Dominio() { IdDominio = m.IdDominio }));
```